# WebSockets + React: Should I use a single connection for multiple functions?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, websocket

I added a WebSocket API through AWS API Gateway on my React app.
I originally added it to build a chat messaging section, however, I soon realized how useful it could be for other things in the app that might need real-time updates.

I had an idea, and that is to store the socket in a React context so it's accessible from all the components of the app and that should work fine, without re-establishing a connection every time a component mounts.

Now, the question is, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Hence, create a socket connection that I can then take advantage of for multiple functions? Say for instance, "is online" status.

The alternative is to create yet another socket API but is that really necessary?

Keep in mind I'm using a serverless framework (API) with lambda functions on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on the applications planned scale, keeping in mind that as the app usage grows you may want to refine the endpoint architecture and code.

Remember that an auth endpoint/api for example may only need to be accessed a few times over a chat interaction endpoint/api. For scalability (and cost per endpoint call too) id be looking at keeping them separate.